# Create Report Showing The Notes Created for Organisations

Tags: civireport, reports

I want to create a report that shows the most recent note that has been created for each organisation. When I looked at modifying one of the existing reports, I could not find in any of the reports, the option to include the standard notes field. Have I missed it or do I need to create a custom report?

I know I may be able to achieve this through Drupal Views but would rather create a report if necessary.

(I am using version 4.7.28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think you need a custom report for that. I dont know whether you can programm such a report your self, if not you might ask someone from the community to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks Jaap for your answer. I haven't created a custom report before but will have a go now and see how I get on!